# grunt watch ignored jshint options

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

I had used `grunt-contrib-watch` for months in my project. But since last week it is corrupt.
I used it to watch for file changes and launch `jshint` or `less` task. All works fine. But today `grunt watch` ignores my `.jshintrc` config file. So it is not correctly applying my ruleset.

If I run my `jshint` task all files are correctly linted. Run the same from `watch` some options are ignored ...

my config looks like the following:

```
    jshint: {
                options: {
                    jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
                },
                grunt: 'Gruntfile.js',
                files : [ '**/*.js' ]
            },
    ...
      watch:{
                jshint:{
                    files: '<%= jshint.files %>',
                    tasks: ['jshint:files']
                }
            }
```

The follwoing error is produced, for every .js file:

```
>> /Users/mybecks/Git/project/foobar/reuse.es.js
>> window is not defined
```

Why does it stopped working correctly?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 1):

add a comment to the top of every failing script:

```
/*global window */
```

read more about what that means here: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#global

dont know though why that did not occuure earlier...